# django no renderiza el template

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion con django.
La estructura de carpetas es la siguiente:

en mi archivo settings.py tengo:

\UnitedHR\UnitedHR\settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/templates/"),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

En mi plantilla base tengo:

\UnitedHR\website2\UnitedHR\templates\base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        {% block Tittle %}
        {% endblock Tittle %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
    {% block Body %}
    {% endblock Body %}
</body>
<footer>
    {% block Footer %}
    {% endblock Footer %}
</footer>
</html>
```

y en la applicacion que estoy tratando de mostrar, tengo:

\UnitedHR\applications\home\templates\Home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block Tittle %}
    United HR
{% endblock Tittle %}
{% block Body %}
    <h1>HOME</h1>
{% endblock Body %}
{% block Footer %}
{% endblock Footer %}
```

Si no uso la plantilla base, la pagina carga normalmente.

En cambio, al incluir la plantilla base.py, me aparece el siguiente error

TemplateDoesNotExist at /
base.html

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
Error during template rendering
base.html
1   {% extends 'base.html' %}
2   
3   {% block Tittle %}
4       United HR
5   {% endblock Tittle %}
6   
7   
8   {% block Body %}
9       <h1>United HR</h1>
10  {% endblock Body %}
11
```

no logro entender porque pasa esto.
Alguien mas podria ayudarme a ver mi error?
Saludos y gracias por leer.

Comment: Es necesario que compartas bien la estructura de tu proyecto (directorios, archivos).

Answer (score 1):

En el settings, la parte de DIRS dejalo en blanco solo con los corchetes, cuando utilizas esa estructura lo que indicas es que vas a centralizar todos los templates en una sola carpeta llamada templates en este caso. por lo cual Django Engine trata de buscar algo, pero creo que el directorio no existe. Si lo dejas en blanco podras trabajar con los templates a nivel de cada aplicacion y no a nivel de proyecto.

Comment: gracias por la informacion, ya estoy claro con este tema.